# Organizing a list of items into two columns

Tags: lists, multicol

Is it possible in `LaTeX` to divide the following list of items into two columns:

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper]{article}

\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}

\section*{Section 01}
\begin{itemize}[noitemsep,nolistsep]
    \item item 1
    \item item 2
    \item item 3
    \item item 4
    \item item 5
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

Here is the output:

[image]

I would like to have items 1, item 2, item 3 in the left column while item 5 and item 6 on the right one. Would this possible using `LaTeX`? I am actually looking for something like the following image:

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `multicol` package.

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper]{article}

\usepackage{enumitem,multicol}

\begin{document}

\section*{Section 01}
\begin{itemize}[noitemsep,nolistsep]
\begin{multicols}{2}
    \item item 1
    \item item 2
    \item item 3
    \item item 4
    \item item 5
\end{multicols}
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank Kumar. Can I have your thoughts on how I can adjust the location where the column is divided? I mean can I move the border of the cell to the left and right?

Comment: @A2009 You mean where the column is broken and next column gets started?

Comment: What if i wanna use `enumerate` instead?

Comment: @Misaki: Use the same strategy. If you want numbers to increase horizontally use `tasks` package instead of `enumerate`.

Answer (score 5):

The following solution worked for me. However, I am not sure if it is the best solution.

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper]{article}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{multicol}

\begin{document}

\section*{Section 01}

\begin{multicols}{2}
    \begin{itemize}[noitemsep,nolistsep]
        \item item 1
        \item item 2
        \item item 3
        \item item 4
        \item item 5
    \end{itemize}
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

Here is the output:

[image]